# Spring Beans - Spring finds two beans instead of one

Tags: java, spring, testng, autowired

I am trying to do something here with Spring and TestNG. Pretty new to both, and just copy-pasting some code from here and there to try to make a new feature in an existing codebase.

Pretty much the gist is like this:

I have my source code. I need a bean in there, so in my Spring XML configuration file, I do:

```
<bean id="bean1" class="com.mypackage.MyClass" />
```

Then I have my code in MyClass.java where I go and do:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("bean1")
private MyClass myBean;

public void myCallingFunction(final MyInput input) {
    myBean.myFunction(input.getList().get(0));
}
```

I have my test code as follows:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("getMyBean")
private MyClass myBean;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("MyBean")
private MyClass myBean2;

@Test(expectedExceptions = ValidationException.class)
public void testExceptionCase() throws ValidationException {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("SomeString");

    MyInput input = new MyInput();
    input.setList(list);

    context.checking(new Expectations() {
        {
            oneOf(myBean).myFunction(with(any(String.class)));
            will(throwException(new ValidationException()));
        }
    });

    myBean2.myCallingFunction(input);
    context.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```

And a 'test' bean like:

```
    @Bean
    public MyClass getMyClass() {
        return context.mock(MyClass.class);
    }
```

When I'm running this test now, I get the below:

```
not all expectations were satisfied
[testng] expectations:
[testng]   expected once, never invoked: myBean.myFunction(ANYTHING); throws <com.mypackage.ValidationException>
[testng]    at org.jmock.Mockery.assertIsSatisfied(Mockery.java:196)
[testng]    at com.mypackage.test.testExceptionCase(MyFileTest.java:51)
[testng]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[testng]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[testng]    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.run(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:175)
[testng]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[testng]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[testng]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I need two beans. One 'mocked', one not mocked.
How can I make this work?

**EDIT:** I totally messed up the naming here. Was being hasty. I'll edit this question with proper names.

Comment: Are you done with your renaming? It's still a bit confusing. Why do you have a bean named `getMyBean` and where did you define it? Where is the bean `MyBean` coming from? Where is your `callingFunction` located? You want to have two `MyClass` instances in your test, but your production code  uses only one.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have three beans of type `MyClass` in your context.
In your test you actually wire the beans named `getMyBean` and `MyBean` using the `@Qualifier` annotation. Your test bean has the name `getMyClass`. So you actually add a third one instead of overriding the `getMyBean` bean.

To achieve the desired behaviour define your test bean like this:

```
@Bean(name="getMyBean")
public MyClass mockedMyClass() {
    return context.mock(MyClass.class);
}
```

Now it overrides the bean definition of your "productive" bean `getMyBean` with the mocked one.

EDIT: I just saw that you have *five* beans. I missed `bean1` and the xml config bean named `QuarantineHelper`. Honestly, you should give your classes, objects and variables better names. Even when you just ask a question. It is really hard not getting confused.

So you have five beans. And there is no bean with the names defined you want to inject in the production and test code. I have no idea how your spring context can be loaded with this configuration. Did you configure TestNG to set up the spring context? Normally you extend `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` and provide a context configuration with `@ContextConfiguration`

Comment: You're totally right, I've sort of messed up the naming. I'll go ahead and edit it and make the question a bit proper-er. Thanks for answering! I think I get what you mean. If what you said works, I'll totally accept your answer. :)